# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() --- I don't use boolean elementsin my arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing

I got this error: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I did some researches and this error usually appears when you have an array with boolean elements,
but in my program, there only are arrays with int elements.
I have a matrix (A) and I want to order the rows by the amount of "unknowns numbers" in each row
(-1 are the unknowns numbers).
I also want to put these ordered rows inside a list (list_1).
The error appears when I try to get the index of an array that's in my list of rows (List_1).

I hope you understand what I'm trying to explain.
I'm a beginner and I just got started with arrays.
Thx for the help! :)

Here's a part of the code:

```
import numpy as np
from colorama import Fore


list_2 = [[-1,9,4,2,-1,6,-1,-1,-1],
        [-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,4,-1,1,-1],
        [7,8,3,-1,-1,-1,2,-1,-1],
        [-1,4,3,-1,7,5,1,8,2],
        [8,5,6,-1,3,2,9,-1,4],
        [-1,-1,-1,-1,9,8,-1,6,-1],
        [-1,-1,7,8,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1],
        [-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,3,4,-1,7],
        [4,6,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,3,1]]
A = np.array(list_2)

list_1 = []


print(Fore.RED, "Rows with less than 5 unknowns numbers:")
for i in range (0,9):
    S = 0
    for nr in A[i,:]:
        if nr == -1:
            S = S + 1
    if S <= 5:
        if len(list_1) > 0:
            append_last = True
            for item in list_1:
                S2 = 0
                for nr in item:
                    if nr == -1:
                        S2 = S2 + 1
                if S < S2:
                    list_1.insert(list_1.index(item),A[i,:])
                    append_last = False
                    break
            if append_last == True:
                list_1.append(A[i,:])
        else:
            list_1.append(A[i,:])

print(Fore.WHITE, list_1)
```

I tried to implement prints on my code and did some research on the internet, but none worked.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is likely coming from this line: list_1.insert(list_1.index(item),A[i,:]). Here you are trying to find the index of an array (item) within a list of arrays (list_1). Numpy doesn't support the operation list_1.index(item) when item and the elements of list_1 are numpy arrays.

The problem is here

list_1.insert(list_1.index(item),A[i,:])

Here is the corrected line in the updated code:

list_1.insert(j,A[i,:])

And also make a change in your loop:

for j, item in enumerate(list_1):

Full code :

```
    if S <= 5:
        if len(list_1) > 0:
            append_last = True
            for j, item in enumerate(list_1):
                S2 = 0
                for nr in item:
                    if nr == -1:
                        S2 = S2 + 1
                if S < S2:
                    list_1.insert(j,A[i,:])
                    append_last = False
                    break
            if append_last == True:
                list_1.append(A[i,:])
        else:
            list_1.append(A[i,:])

print(Fore.WHITE, list_1)
```

Comment: That's not going to fix anything. There's no `j` variable.

Comment: U r right - change the loop too: for j, item in enumerate(list_1):

Comment: Wohooo!!!! Glad it worked !